# Anarchy with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, dual-boot, multiboot

I currently have a Ubuntu 20.04 installation, and I was wondering if it's possible to use Anarchy to install Arch along with that, as a dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "Can I dual-boot into two Linux installations?" the answer is Yes.

If the question is "Can I do this with Anarchy?" the answer is probably yes, you need to try.